# WP8 JSON Deserialisation of Arrays nested in Arrays nested in Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json, windows-phone-8, expandoobject

I want to do something quite simple.
I just want to take a JSON string (which I have) and populate a whole bunch of stuff with it.
The problem for me is that there are arrays hidden in array inside more arrays, and I can't get at my data.

I tried standard deserialization like so ...

```
var apiData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

But this only lets me get into the top layer - what is in rootObject

I tried making a dictionary ...

```
Dictionary<string, dynamic> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
```

but that doesn't let me drill down either (or I can't make it).
I have set up my c# using json2c#

I've been all over the internet including here.
The closest I have got to creating anything close is an expandoObject

```
var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();
        dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, converter);
```

which I can see from the debugger is keeping everything structured as I would like but I've no idea how to get some of the stuff out.
Long story short, its been two days now and I'm bashing my head against a brick wall.
I just want to be able to get the data out of the JSON string and I can't change that string as its not mine.

```
public class NewsArticlesList
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string snippet { get; set; }
}

public class jobsList
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string titleLinkUrl { get; set; }
    public List<object> relatedSearchesList { get; set; }
    public string formattedTraffic { get; set; }
    public int trafficBucketLowerBound { get; set; }
    public int interestLevel { get; set; }
    public string interestColor { get; set; }
    public List<NewsArticlesList> newsArticlesList { get; set; }
    public double startTime { get; set; }
    public string shareUrl { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
}

public class jobsByDateList
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string formattedDate { get; set; }
    public List<jobsList> jobsList { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string summaryMessage { get; set; }
    public double dataUpdateTime { get; set; }
    public List<jobsByDateList> jobsByDateList { get; set; }
    public string oldestVisibleDate { get; set; }
    public bool lastPage { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is these lists inside lists inside lists.
I can get to jobsListByDate.formattedDate but I can't get anywhere near jobsListByDate.jobsList.titleLinkUrl let alone inside the NewsArticlesList to those sources.

Apologies if this is super-easy (I hope it is) but I'm a WP8 noob.
I know there are similar threads on SO, but none of them seem to deal with such deep arrays.

Comment: Could this be the issue?  
    public List<object> relatedSearchesList { get; set; }

Comment: It is one of the issues. All of the lists are a problem. I don't know how to access them.

Comment: please post json source or link to it

Comment: Sussed it. Answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was not stipulating which branch to go down and so it was confused.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(apiData.jobsByDateList[0].jobsList[0].interestLevel);
```

I was trying to get in using

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(apiData.jobsByDateList.jobsList.interestLevel);
```

and intellisense was freaking out.

With the [0] I'm now able to drill in just fine and don't need the expandoobject. Just needed to sleep on it. :-)